# Preg_replace pattern but exclude some matches

Tags: preg-replace

I'm trying to use preg_match to match all capitlized words in a string, yet I want to exclude some of the matches.

```
$line1 = "This is PATTERN that matches";
$line2 = "I don't want to match";
$line3 = "I'm not matching correctly";
```

So my regex is:

```
preg_replace('/\b([A-Z]*)\b/','<span style="font-weight:bold;">$1</span>',$text);
```

In the first line it will correctly match PATTERN and bold it. But in line2 it bolds "I" and in line3 it bolds "I" from I'm as well. I've tried various alerternatives using [^] in the regex, but don't seem to be getting anywhere.

So to exclude "I" or even "PM", or a list of letters/words that might be capitilized that I don't want included, what would I use?

Answer (score 0):

How about:

```
$str = "I want to match PATTERN but not PM";
$str = preg_replace('/\b(?!PM)(?!I)([A-Z]+)\b/','<span style="font-weight:bold;">$1</span>',$str);
echo "$str\n";
```

**Output:**

```
I want to match <span style="font-weight:bold;">PATTERN</span> but not PM
```

Comment: Thank you. I ended up solving it with:

    $text = preg_replace('/\b([A-Z]*)(?<!I|PM|AM|ABCD|SMA)\b/','<span style="font-weight:bold;">$1</span>',$text);

But this seems very similar to your answer. But I appreciate your time none the less.

Max